# nx EINVALIDPACKAGENAME when using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, monorepo

I have an nx monorepo it was working fine until recently, and now whenever I use `npm install` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "@package-name" of package "@package-name@file:/Users/usename/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/packages/package-name": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

I tried to delete `package-lock.json`, didn't work.
I checked in my commit history if there was any change to `package.json` but there was none, and both solutions didn't work.

I successfully used `npm install` on my raspberry pi by changing my npm version to v6.14. But then I noticed the error was also present on my MAC with npm v9.2.

nx.json:

```
{
  "extends": "nx/presets/npm.json",
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "nx/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": [
          "build",
          "lint",
          "test",
          "e2e"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "targetDefaults": {
    "lint": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintrc.json"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "^default",
        "{workspaceRoot}/jest.preset.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ntffi-lending"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nx-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/js": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/node": "15.3.3",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.7.1",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "jest": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.1",
    "nx": "15.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@nftfi/js": "git+ssh://git@github.com:NFTfi-Genesis/nftfi.js.git",
    "bnc-sdk": "^4.6.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@abis": [
        "packages/abis/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@fs-helper": [
        "packages/fs-helper/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@nftfi-helper": [
        "packages/nftfi-helper/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@packages/*": [
        "packages/*/src"
      ],
      "@utils": [
        "packages/utils/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@wrapper": [
        "packages/wrapper/src/index.ts"
      ],
      "@arcade-helper": [
        "packages/arcade-helper/src/index.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./packages",
    "./apps"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

npm debug log

```
0 verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@9.2.0
2 info using node@v16.15.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/username/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/username/.npmrc Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 8ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm i
21 verbose argv "i"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 16ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-12-29T19_56_31_220Z-
26 verbose logfile /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-12-29T19_56_31_220Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 34ms
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
32 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 0ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree:init Completed in 673ms
36 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
37 silly idealTree buildDeps
38 timing idealTree Completed in 675ms
39 timing command:i Completed in 679ms
40 verbose stack Error: Invalid package name "@package-name" of package "@package-name@file:/Users/username/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/packages/package-name": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
40 verbose stack     at invalidPackageName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:111:15)
40 verbose stack     at Result.setName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:158:11)
40 verbose stack     at new Result (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:147:10)
40 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:59:15)
40 verbose stack     at Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1057:22)
40 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:928:36)
40 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDeps] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:775:31)
40 verbose stack     at Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:206:29)
40 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
40 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:156:5)
41 verbose cwd /Users/username/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name
42 verbose Darwin 22.1.0
43 verbose node v16.15.1
44 verbose npm  v9.2.0
45 error code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
46 error Invalid package name "@package-name" of package "@package-name@file:/Users/username/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/packages/package-name": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
47 verbose exit 1
48 timing npm Completed in 736ms
49 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1672343791274
50 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1672343791275
51 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1672343791948
52 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1672343791949
53 verbose code 1
54 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
54 error     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-12-29T19_56_31_220Z-debug-0.log
```

Do I have to stay at node v6.14 forever ? How could I solve this for npm 9 and above ? Knowing that this was working fine yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Manually go to the folder where the folder the package you want to update is located. Assuming based on your question it's `file:/Users/usename/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/packages` From there, there run `npm install package-name. There's no need for the "@".

As far at the issue goes, it's not directly clear what you're running, because @package-name is not located anywhere other than in your debug log. If you're attempting to to pass in @package-name as a variable name to install packages, it seems that's not working how you're expecting.

This: `@package-name@file:/Users/username/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/packages/package-name` should look like this: `file:/Users/username/Documents/Workspace/my-projects/monorepo-name/packages/package-name`